# Does the Spyder profiler use cProfile or Profile?

Tags: python, spyder, cprofile

Does the Spyder profiler use cProfile or Profile? I ask this because I'm running the Spyder profiler on a slow program and I don't want it to get much slower.

Comment: Are you using the `spyder-profiler` plugin?

Comment: @kfb I installed spyder using homebrew on my Mac. It came with the profiler. I run it by going to `Run > Profile`.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Spyder to know what profiler is active by default, but [this page](http://sjara.github.io/spyder-profiler/) implies cProfile: "`The tree shows the results calculated by python’s module ‘cProfile’`".

Comment: You could always directly inspect the code in site-packages to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Spyder and it has inbuilt-feature `profile(run-> profile)` which give time taken b y different function. It also can use to for comparison of two results.
Spyder profiler use cProfile. you can check from here

http://sjara.github.io/spyder-profiler/